# .= syntax php undefined variable

Tags: php

I got this error message

```
Undefined variable: x in ../../../../.php on line 35
```

I get the error on this line.

```
$x .= $y->getContent();
```

This line of code is in a `foreach` loop.

How do I get rid of the error message.

If I replace the `.=` with just `=` I'm not getting the correct output.

I hope I provided enough information

And what does `.=` do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: U probably need to set $x = '' ; before the loop !!

Comment: perhaps you are trying to append to an uninitialised variable? try adding `$x = '';` above your `foreach () { ... }` code.

Comment: set $x = null; before $x .= $y->getContent();

Comment: first define it as blank value before foreach bcoz u append value in it so must be define

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.=` is used (in your code) to concatenate the value of `$x` with result of `->getContent()` call on `$y` and write the result back into `$x`.

Is like write `$x = $x.$y`

Of course if `$x` does not exists (like in your example I suppose; with "not exists" I mean that hasn't a value), regardless how you wrote your expression, this will fail. Moreover, `$x` and `$y` will be considerated strings so, please pay attention to your variables type (you can't concatenate two object, for example)

Answer (score 1):

`$x.=$y` is a shortcut for `$x=$x.$y`

so if `$x = 'cat'` and `$y = 'fish'` then the result of `$x.=$y` is `'catfish'`

As to your error, you need to create the variable $x 1st, out side the loop:

```
$x='';
foreach($var as $y){
    $x.=$y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = '';
foreach()
{
   $x .= $y->getContent();
}
```

**it is must to define $x becouse you are append value in $x **

Answer (score 0):

Define x before your loop :
$x = '';

Answer (score 0):

The `.=` operator is a string operator to concatenate strings.

`$x .= $y`is the same as `$x = $x.$y`

You could read about [string operator
s](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in the official PHP reference

If $x don't exist you can't concatenate it with $y, this is the reason of the error message.